# Why is Alchemy eth_getLogs not finding event logs for AaveV3 Supply events?

Tags: events, alchemy

I have created a Node project that connects to Alchemy via ethers. I am trying to capture all [Supply events for AaveV3](https://etherscan.io/address/0x87870Bca3F3fD6335C3F4ce8392D69350B4fA4E2#events)

However, when I use the `getLogs` function, and use the contract address as the `address` field, it finds no event logs whatsoever.

```
const AAVE_V3_CONTRACT_ADDRESS = '0x87870Bca3F3fD6335C3F4ce8392D69350B4fA4E2'; 
const provider = new ethers.AlchemyProvider('mainnet', ALCHEMY_API_KEY);

async function fetchSupplyEvents(minAmount, maxAmount) {
   const logs = await provider.getLogs({
      address: AAVE_V3_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
   });
   console.log(logs); //returns []
   ...
```

You might have noticed, I have totally omited most fields from the getLogs function, because it seems to be unable to capture ANY events that have happened to this contract. There have definitely been events omited, see the link above.

**So my question is**

Why is Alchemy failing to find any logs when I call `eth_getLogs`?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `topics` field in the filter object you're passing to `getLogs`, you need to include the event signature in the `topics` field.

You gonna to find the signature of the `Supply` event in AaveV3, you can have it like that `const supplyEventSignature = ethers.utils.id("Supply(address,address,uint256,uint256)");`

here is the full code, dont forget to replace the `ALCHEMY_API_KEY`

```
const ethers = require("ethers");

const ALCHEMY_API_KEY = 'your_alchemy_api_key';
const AAVE_V3_CONTRACT_ADDRESS = '0x87870Bca3F3fD6335C3F4ce8392D69350B4fA4E2';
const provider = new ethers.AlchemyProvider('mainnet', ALCHEMY_API_KEY);

const supplyEventSignature = ethers.utils.id("Supply(address,address,uint256,uint256)");

async function fetchSupplyEvents(minAmount, maxAmount, fromBlock = 0, toBlock = 'latest') {
    const logs = await provider.getLogs({
        address: AAVE_V3_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
        topics: [supplyEventSignature],
        fromBlock,
        toBlock,
    });

    console.log(logs);
}

fetchSupplyEvents();
```

Comment: According to the docs, topics is an optional field.